# Default attachment when has_one_attached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

I have a user model with a `has_one_attached :avatar`, using `ActiveStorage`.
Avatar is optional, but when it isn't present I want to show a default instead. I store all attachments on Amazon S3, and prefer to store the default there as well.

I'd much prefer if I was able to use variant methods on the default avatar as well.

```
user.avatar.variant(resize: "100x100")
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this? Can I create some sort of default attachment that isn't linked to any specific record and use that when the avatar isn't present?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of attaching the default image, just check if there is an image attached and if not, display the default image. The `present?` method will not work in this case, use `attached?` instead.

```
def display_avatar(user)
  if user.avatar.attached?
    user.avatar
  else
    'default.png'
  end
end
```

Comment: The problem with that solution is that I don't get access to variants and it isn't stored on S3 (that could be hardcoded tho)

Comment: Just access the variant method in the view. I wouldn't store the default on S3, just include as an asset.

Answer (score -1):

There are two methods,

1. Default

In model use this,(assuming you are using paperclip gem)

:default_url => "/assets/:style/missing.jpeg"

2.Manual

You have to add helper method as below,

```
  def avatar_check user
      if user.avatar.image.present?
        image_tag user.image_url :thumb
      else
        image_tag 'default.jpg'
      end
    end
```

Save your default.jpg in assets.

In view call below,

```
User.all.each do |u|
= avatar_check u
```

And I am not sure about varient

Comment: I am not using papercip so the first method is unfortunately not doable. The second method does not work either as it doesn't work with `variant` and I am creating a API, so image_tag isn't usable. 

Using ActiveStorage.